# Best Practices for Designing Around Presence/Absence of Home Button on Tablets?

Tags: design, web-applications, ipad

Older iPads used to have a home button:

[image]

Newer iPads don't have it. They have a line on the screen you're supposed to swipe up to get to the home screen:

[image]

Now if an app has a row of links or buttons at the bottom of the screen, it has to leave extra space for that line on the screen.

How are people handling this? Am I supposed to do device sniffing to figure out whether to leave that extra space for that line? I thought device sniffing was deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile devices feature complex screen layouts, with camera insets, rounded screens, and hovering navigation elements. Web applications cannot query the exact geometry of these features. However, CSS provides a [“safe area inset” environment variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) that indicates how much padding you must add to get an unobstructed rectangular content region, and is therefore [suggested by Apple for websites that target modern iOS devices](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/).